# Laravel notifcations email change laravel text on top of email

Tags: laravel, notifications

I set up email notification and modified the text, what I wondering is there a way to change the Laravel text at the top of the email and the @2016 Laravel at the footer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `config/app.php` file.

Change the `'name' => 'Laravel'` to the name of your website.